# Waiting logic to track DB Table Changes

Tags: c#, oracle, wait, sqldependency

I have a web service that inserts a row into a Database Table.

[image]

After this a windows service will read this table and updates this table.

- Inserts a Blob into FILE_IMAGE column
- STATUS to COMPLETE

My Web Service has to wait till this table STATUS and FILE_IMAGE column gets updated and then read the FILE_IMAGE.

My doubt is : What logic is ideal for my web service to wait for the table to get updated.
I dont want to use Thread.Sleep or something similar to that. My database is Oracle and code behind is C#.

Answer (score 0):

You could write an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger on the oracle table which sends the ROWID to another web service which performs the necessary steps.  Thread.Sleep will always have the potential of not waiting long enough.